# How to find a table using selenium and vba on webpage that uses iframes?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, iframe, web-scraping

The below code worked up until a few days ago to go to the url, find the table and import the contents of the table into Excel. I then did some other formatting to get the table into the appropriate rows and columns. But now this code cannot locate the table. I do not fully understand the "Set a = .FindElementsByTag("iframe")(2)" and the ".SwitchToFrame 1". But my general understanding is that this portion of the code switches to a different frame which then extracts the internal url, which then is used to get the data form the table.

I need help identifying what to change in order to get the intended "url2", which is "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT__QigQ9cJV03ohUkeK5dgQjfAbJqxrc68bXh9Is1WFST8wjxMxDy7hYUCFHynqRvInsANUI22GdIM/pubhtml?gid=817544912&single=true&chrome=false&widget=false&headers=false" url. *note: I do not use this docs.google url because I do not know if this url will change periodically. I know the rosterresource.com/mlb-roster-grid url will stay consistent.

I have tried changing some of the integers for "Set a = .FindElementsByTag("iframe")(2)" and the ".SwitchToFrame 1", but I am doing that blindly since I am not familiar with this art of the code.

`````
Sub GetRRgrid()
    '"Selenium type library" is a reference used
    Dim d As WebDriver, a As Object
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const url = "https://www.rosterresource.com/mlb-roster-grid/"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .Get url

        Set a = .FindElementsByTag("iframe")(2)

        .SwitchToFrame 1

        url2 = .FindElementByCss("iframe").Attribute("src")
        .Get url2
        ele = .FindElementByTag("tbody").Attribute("innerText")
        d.Close
    End With
    ' other processes t format the data after it is imported
end sub
````
`````

Comment: So, imagine the `d.FindElementsByTag("iframe")` as a collection of objects. More specifically it's a collection of all the `<iframe></iframe>` elements in an HTML document. To get access to each one of these elements you use the (i) notation. So d.FindElementsByTag("iframe")(2) is the 3rd object in this collection.

Comment: Do you know which (i) notation I should be using? that .attribute("src") should equal "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT__QigQ9cJV03ohUkeK5dgQjfAbJqxrc68bXh9Is1WFST8wjxMxDy7hYUCFHynqRvInsANUI22GdIM/pubhtml?gid=817544912&single=true&chrome=false&widget=false&headers=false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Getting the iframe and switching to it:**

You need to pass the iframe element (*identifier* argument) to `SwitchToFrame`, you are then within that document and can interact with its contents. No need to `.get` on that with Selenium. You have to switch to `.SwitchToDefaultContent` to go back to parent document.

You can identify the iframe in question in a number of ways. Modern browsers are optimized for css selectors so I usually go with those. The css equivalent of

```
.FindElementByTag("iframe")
```

is

```
.FindElementByCss("iframe")
```

Your iframe is the first (and only) so I wouldn't bother gathering a set of webElements and indexing into it. Also, you want to try for a short selector of a single element where possible to be more efficient.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Const URL As String = "https://www.rosterresource.com/mlb-roster-grid/"
    Set d = New ChromeDriver

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL

        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByCss("iframe")

        Stop

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Writing to Excel (`.AsTable.ToExcel`) :**

Something I only just discovered, haven't seen documented anywhere, and am excited by, is that there is a method to write the table direct to Excel:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Const URL As String = "https://www.rosterresource.com/mlb-roster-grid/"
    Set d = New ChromeDriver

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL

        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByTag("iframe")
        .FindElementByCss(".waffle").AsTable.ToExcel ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        Stop

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This method seems interesting and may help me quite a bit for writing it as a table to Excel. But I am getting an error when I get to ".FindElementByCss(".waffle").AsTable.ToExcel". "NoSuchElementError. Element not found for Css= .waffle".

Comment: Check what the class name is for the table in the webpage. It appears as that for me.   You could also use  .FindElementByCss("table").AsTable.ToExcel

Comment: Are you sure you have switched to the iframe as well?

Comment: I accepted the top. That appears to work since I get to that iframe ok (no error message). Even though I am unsure if that is the correct iframe. How do I know that I am in the iframe correctly? I am still unable to get this portion to work: .FindElementByCss(".waffle").AsTable.ToExcel ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"). It cannot find that .waffle element.

Comment: what happens with  .FindElementByCss("table").AsTable.ToExcel  ? Strange because class is definitely there and has worked each time I have run it. You could also try adding a wait before but that really shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: .FindElementByCss("table").AsTable.ToExcel still gives me an error of "element not found for Css=table"

Comment: verify you are definately swtched to the iframe

Comment: this is a "run time error 7", if that matters. How do I verify that I am switched to that iframe?

Comment: Try selecting any element within the iframe

Comment: Maybe I am not switched to the iframe. I tried: .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByCss("iframe"), then next line: url2 = .FindElementByCss("iframe").Attribute("src"). But I get "element not found for Css=iframe"

Comment: When you run my code exactly as is, bottom version, was that producing an error?

Comment: when i run your code, bottom version, I get: run-time error '7': NoSuchElementError Element not found for Css=.waffle

Comment: If you step through slowly with f8 does that make a difference?

Comment: No difference if I step through w/ F8

Comment: I’ll have a look in 20-30 mins to see if I can find a way to reproduce

Comment: I can't replicate error. The code above works every time :-(

Comment: Ok, I am going to try this on my home laptop in a few hours and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing for this question. Thanks to QHarr for the guidance.

```
Public Sub GetRRrostergrid()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Const URL As String = "https://www.rosterresource.com/mlb-roster-grid/"
    Dim URL2 As String
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Sheet20.Activate

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .Get URL
        URL2 = .FindElementByClass("post_content").FindElementByTag("iframe").Attribute("src")
        .Get URL2
        .FindElementByCss(".waffle").AsTable.ToExcel ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RRchart").Range("b1")
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```