# Using VBA Selenium webdriver to scrape a table, but it's too slow

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using selenium web driver in VBA to scrape a table, but it's too slow to actually utilize. I need some improvements on my VBA code to actually use it.

I had been using IE automation on this particular website. Copying whole HTML table and pasting it was quite fast process. But, as the website did undergo some changes, I can no longer use IE on the website.
So I tried to set up a selenium web driver, and uses Chrome to scrape the very same table. As I can't copy the whole table (Because, I don't know how), I have to write down 'for each' statement to repeat copy and paste process for each cell of the table. Unfortunately, by doing that it took a almost a half second for each cell, which make it kinda unusable.
The code I wrote do works, but it's way slower as I mentioned. I might assign target table as a web element or something, to speed up the process. (I tried and failed)
It seems to me that, each 'for each statement' making the web driver to search through website, slows down the whole process, but I'm not entirely sure.

```
Sub NewSeleniumScraper(ByVal metricname, ByVal metricDate, Optional testval As String)


Dim WD As New Selenium.WebDriver
Dim Chrome As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheetsname As String
Lastrow = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count


For Each tr In WD.FindElementByClass("table-wrap").FindElementByTag("tbody").FindElementsByTag("tr")
    c = 1
        For Each td In tr.FindElementsByTag("td")
            ws.Cells(Lastrow + r, c).Value = td.Text
            c = c + 1
        Next td
    r = r + 1
Next tr
```

The code I wrote copy each value in a searched table and paste it below the last row in the worksheet, one cell by one. I want to speed up the process, as currently it took like a 0.5 seconds for each cell, which makes it a hour long process to copy a table.

This is how the table is structured.

(all is class name)

```
"table-wrap"
"theader", "tbody"
many "tr" (for each row)
many "td" (for each cell in the row)
```

What I need to scrape is Value of td.

Comment: Would it be possible to share a URL? It might be possible to use an HTTP request to get the data without having to use a browser. This would be significantly more efficient. Also, you should write the data in an array and then print this array in one go into excel. That should also contribute to the overall efficiency.

Comment: Seeing the html in question for the table would help as would having the url.

Comment: Check this method of selenium as well [.AsTable.ToExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55654944/6241235)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't share a URl, as it's more of KPI related stuffs. I updated the question with table structure.

Comment: @QHarr I will try the method you posted, I will post how it did go. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: I know this post is 6 months old but I had a similar question to this today and found a solution which I believe to be the best answer. Link to duplicate post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61028387/seleniumbasic-vba-fastest-loop-of-webelements-using-a-webelement-method

Answer (score 2):

Thanks you all for the comments, it helped me a lot.
I had a several change on the code

1. I wasn't able to 'set' all rows as an element(not sure it's the
   right term)

I figured out that you don't need to 'Dim' an web element. I removed the 'dim'
statement and just put 'set' statement for the web elements. (I am not sure that this speeds up the process or not)

2. I wasn't able to populate an array with values of the table.

I now know that, you should 'redim' array as 2D array with fixed size, I failed because I tried to populate a dynamic 1D array as if it is 2D array.

Below is new code.

```
Set trs = WD.FindElementByClass("table-wrap").FindElementByTag("tbody").FindElementsByTag("tr")

rcount = trs.Count
ccount = trs(1).FindElementsByTag("td").Count
ReDim Preserve dataArray(1 To rcount, 1 To ccount)



r = 1
For Each tr In trs

    c = 1

    Set tds = tr.FindElementsByTag("td")

        For Each td In tds
            dataArray(r, c) = td.Text
            c = c + 1
        Next td
    r = r + 1
Next tr


Range(Cells(Lastrow + 1, 1), Cells(Lastrow + rcount, ccount)).Value = dataArray
```

I hope this helps someone in a situation similar to mine.

Answer (score 0):

It takes a long time because you are looping through all the elements of the table, and apparently there are a lot of elements in that table.  Can you not just turn on the Macro recorder, navigate to the page you want to import data from, click the object that points to the table you want, and import all data in one-go?  When you are done, you will have all the code you need.  Try that and see how you get along.

Comment: Macro recorder only give me a code like this.
'Import' doesn't work as it's based on IE and the website I have to scrape provide IE support no longer.

Comment: Range("A5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste