# SeleniumBasic VBA Fastest Loop of WebElements using a WebElement method

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm noticing a rather long time for an operation to complete.

I'm using the latest SeleniumBasic for VBA to extract data from a table using a ChromeDriver.
(https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic)

I'm retrieving WebElements and looping through them to get the text value.

I'm assigning the text value to an array of type String.

This operation takes quite a long time when I have a large array (1000's of WebElement objects).

**Question - What is the fastest way to get all the text values?**

Here is my HTML

```
<table class="Tables_Table_0">
    <caption></caption>
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-4">
                Name
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Time
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Number
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Rate
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Other
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Final
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="SOME CLASS">
            <td>
                Name Here</a>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                123.000
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                5
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                8%
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                20
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                300.00
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Each table row has 6 data points, specified by the td tag. I've cut the snippet to only 1 table row but just imagine having 100+ table rows.

VBA Code

```
Dim table As WebElement, tableElements As WebElements, tableData() As String, Element
Dim tableIndex As Integer, tableDataCount As Integer

'Get the table
Set table = bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""Tables_Table_0""]")

'Get the <td> elements
Set tableElements = table.FindElementsByTag("td")

'Assign array size to variable to use later on during loops
tableDataCount = tableElements.Count

'Assign array size            
ReDim tableData(tableDataCount)

'Loop index counter       
tableIndex = 1

'PROBLEM HERE - TAKES TOO LONG WHEN I HAVE A BUNCH OF ROWS IN MY TABLE
'Loop each element and get the Text value            
For Each Element In tableElements
    tableData(tableIndex) = Element.text '
    tableIndex = tableIndex + 1
Next Element
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more research, there is an object called TableElement which can be used.
This extracts HTML tables almost instantly and dumps it in a two dimensional VBA array.

```
'Credits to @florentbr 
Private Sub Iterate_A_Table2()
Dim driver As New FirefoxDriver, Assert As New Assert
driver.Get "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/tables"

Dim tbl As TableElement
Set tbl = driver.FindElementByCss("#table1").AsTable

Dim Data()
Data = tbl.Data
For c = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
  For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
    Debug.Print Data(r, c)
  Next
  Debug.Print Empty
Next

driver.Quit
End Sub
```

Credits to @florentbr -

https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/issues/33#issuecomment-153500008

Answer (score 3):

SeleniumBasic also has a .ToExcel method that makes this even easier:

```
Set tbl = bot.FindElementByCss("#table1").AsTable
tbl.ToExcel Range("A1")
```