# how to get all child elements of a parent in selenium vba?

Tags: vba, selenium, xpath

```
Option Explicit

Sub ex()
Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim htmldiv As Selenium.WebElement
Dim htmlul As Selenium.WebElement
Dim htmlAs As Selenium.WebElements
Dim htmlA As Selenium.WebElement
Dim htmlTable As Selenium.WebElement
Dim TableSection As Selenium.WebElement

Dim TableName As String

URL = "https://www.whoscored.com/Statistics"

sel.Start "Chrome"
sel.Get URL
 
Set htmldiv = sel.FindElementById("top-player-stats")
Set htmlul = sel.FindElementById("top-player-stats-options")

Set htmlAs = htmlul.FindElementsByTag("a")

    For Each htmlA In htmlAs
        TableName = Right(htmlA.Attribute("href"), Len(htmlA.Attribute("href")) - InStr(1, htmlA.Attribute("href"), "#"))
        htmlA.Click
        
Set htmlTable = sel.FindElementById(TableName & "-grid")
    
    For Each TableSection In htmlTable.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id=""top-player-stats-summary-grid""]")
        'Debug.Print htmlTable.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id=""top-player-stats-summary-grid""]").Count
        debug.print TableSection.tagname

    Next TableSection

    Next htmlA
End Sub
```

here htmltable.findelementsbyxpath... gives only one element i.e. table tag itself, but i want to loop through all children of htmltable, so how to do that.whether my xpath method is correct?

Comment: Depends on final purpose. There is a method to write table to sheet in one go without looping available _.AsTable.ToExcel_. Otherwise, you want to loop tr then td.

Comment: cant we loop through children fo table using children property or xpath or something?

Comment: I'm saying why loop when you can write out in one go with the existing method of the webdriver?

Comment: If there an existing method then how to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55654944/6241235

Answer (score 0):

You can build a udf and implement childElementCount and childNodes.
In your code, you can test it with:

```
Debug.Print sel.WebDriver.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].childElementCount", TableSection)

Debug.Print sel.WebDriver.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[0].tagName", TableSection)
Debug.Print sel.WebDriver.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[1].tagName", TableSection)
```

And use this strategy changing the TableSelection element for it's children

Comment: you can remove the ()